WPF GridLength dependency property: cannot convert from System.String
I'm developing a WPF application with this UserControl:
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public GridLength IconColumnWidth
    {
        get { return (GridLength)GetValue(IconColumnWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconColumnWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconColumnWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IconColumnWidth), typeof(GridLength), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(new GridLength(0), new PropertyChangedCallback(SetIconColumnWidth)));

    public static void SetIconColumnWidth(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyUserControl target = (MyUserControl)d;
        target.MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = ((GridLength)e.NewValue);
    }
}

And I'm trying to use it as follow:
<MyUserControl x:Name="Total" Value="{Binding TotalCycles, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" IconColumnWidth="50"  />

However, I'm getting error 'TypeConverter cannot convert from System.String'.
I tried to apply this attribute on my DependencyProperty field
[TypeConverter(typeof(GridLengthConverter))]

but nothing changed.
What am I doing wrong?

You've registered the "owner" of the dependency property as "HmiValue"; one would expect it to be "MyUserControl" for the typical case.

Your explanations and the code snippets you provided are not sufficient to reproduce the error you reported. Therefore, it is impossible to answer your question.

"I tried to apply this attribute on my DependencyProperty field" - you should set the attribute on the property.

@GerrySchmitz sorry, that was a copy-paste typo. Updated code snippet.

@Clemens , the reason is different. The attribute is already set for the GridLength Struct. Setting it for the property is absolutely unnecessary. I have completely repeated the code specified in the question. Everything works without errors for me. So the reason is something else.

@EldHasp thank you for confirming that posted code is working. I'll try to redo that in a new clean sln and I'll let you know.

@EldHasp I tried with a clean sln with just the provided code, still getting the same error. Then I tried specifying property value with {Binding} syntax and it worked (added explanation in my answer below).

See out the repository of my replication of your code: https://github.com/EldHasp/IFrank/ . It works without any errors or exceptions. I couldn't reproduce the problem you wrote.

@EldHasp Thank you for taking the time to prepare a solution and letting me try it. I updated my answer: unfortunately, the issue is still there.

I think your conclusion that the problem is related to your Studio settings is correct. Unfortunately, without being able to reproduce the problem you indicated, I cannot tell you how to solve it. Perhaps other respondents (@GerrySchmitz , @Clemens ) will be able to check my example for reproducing the error.

I finally found a way to solve my issue. Not sure if this is the proper way but since it's working without problems and it's pretty straighforward, I post my solution as accepted answer. I'll be happy to update this post (and eventually change accepted answer) if someone will provide a better solution explaining its advantages.
I tried multiple things, like setting attribute [TypeConverter(typeof(GridLengthConverter))] on property only, on dependency property field only or on both of them - no way to get this working.
Then, I tried to write my custom implementation of GridLengthConverter and applying it as attribute as done before. This started working but it was clunky and unreliable (every time I changed the property value from xaml I got the error again; rebuilding project worked but this does not allowed me to change the property value while the application was running - which is supposed to be the expected behaviour on WPF).
Finally, I simply changed how I was specifying property value in XAML and ended up with this:
<local:MyUserControl
     Margin="20"
     IconColumnWidth="{Binding Source=50}" />

I simply added a {Binding Source=myValue} where I needed to specify value for that property, having 'myValue' equals to desired value.
This syntax works flawlessy even without specifying a TypeConverter (so I deleted my custom converter) and also recognises if I'm specifying a Pixel GridLength or a Star GridLength (proportional value, like "0.5*").
I hope this will help someone else with the same issue.
UPDATE
After cloning source code from EldHasp's comment, I tried it out and found that even a clean solution (which does not give any error to others), it's giving me the same issue.

At this point, I think this is an issue related to my Visual Studio installation. I'll try to uninstall and reinstall it, as soon I'll have a "code free" day (don't know when this will happen...)

"GridLength" is a "complex" (value) object; with multiple constructors. Most dependency examples use "simple" value objects. I suspect the "Binding" allowed the "binding engine" to do more of its thing.
